# Authorized authentication by public key ssh , when active directory disabled account

Tags: pam, active-directory, kerberos, winbind

Good Morning ,

Why can I still authenticate with a public key via ssh while my account is disabled on active directory?

My infrastructure is CentOS and authentication by active directory with winbind and pam.

Is it a hole of security of winbind and pam ? Do you know a solution for this problem ?

Thank's a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Because LDAP authentication and key-pair authentication are two separate authentication regimes, neither of which cares what the other has to say.  SSH will keep trying to use any available means to authenticate until it finds one that works.  This can be mitigated through proper configuration (read up on `pam`, for example).